# MFMailComposeViewController won't appear in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, ios8.1

I have an objective C program that has popover with a list of dates and two buttons "Done" and "Cancel".  When the user hits a date and then the done button, the popover is supposed to disappear and a MFMailViewController window populated with data from that date is supposed to appear.

When I run the program on an iPad with iOS 7, everything works fine - the popover disappears and the mail view appears with the data populated.  When I run it on an iPad with iOS 8.1, the popover disappears but the mail view does not appear.

Using NSLog output, I know that the iPad can send email, the correct date is getting to the method, the MFMailViewController object does exist, and it gets past the line that is supposed to present the controller.  But the controller doesn't appear.

Any help with this would be appreciated because tons of web searches have found nothing helpful.

The end of the method is:

```
NSLog(@"about to present the mail view");
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] == YES){
    NSLog(@"can it email YES");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"can it email NO");
}
NSLog(@"the picker is %@",picker);
[self presentViewController:picker animated:NO completion:NULL];
NSLog(@"leaving method EmailDataFiles");
```

and the output from this code is:

```
about to present the mail view
can it email YES
the picker is <MFMailComposeViewController: 0x1616ac00>
leaving method EmailDataFiles
```

Comment: The popover you mentioned  here is a UIActionSheet?

Comment: No, it's a UIPopoverController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a race condition.. the dismissPopover on the doneButton-action of popoverController and presentViewController of the picker are clashing..

Can you try if the below option works for you ?

```
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:NO completion:NULL];
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I had been wondering if I was running into a race condition.  This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're initializing picker object but this works for me, put inside your if condition:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] == YES){
    NSLog(@"can it email YES");
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailViewController setSubject:@"Subject"];
    [mailViewController setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
    mailViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

    [self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Based on something I read about persistence of the object, I changed the declaration of the MFMailComposeViewController object to be in the interface for the class.  The initialization I'm using is:[code]     picker = nil;
    picker = [MFMailComposeViewController new];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;[\code]

Comment: Thats fine with the declaration. Did you try above code?

Comment: I added the set of the modalPresentationStyle but it didn't help.  The presentModalViewController was deprecated in iOS 6.

Comment: I should mention that the original code is the end of a long method that reads and attaches 12 text/csv files to the MFMailComposeViewController as well as setting the to address, the subject, and message contents.